# getting "The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (6.0.1.67)" on Extjs app creation?

Tags: laravel, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6

I installed Sencha successfully. Try to create Sencha application and integrate with Laravel, but on the application creation getting below errors.

```
$ sencha -sdk /var/www/html/simple-laravel-login-authentication-master/public/myapps/ext-6.0.1 generate app loginapp5 /var/www/html/simple-laravel-login-authentication-master/public/myapps/see/loginapp5
```

Error:

> Sencha Cmd v6.2.0.103
>       [ERR] Directory /var/www/html/simple-laravel-login-authentication-master/public/myapps/see/loginapp5/packages
>   creation was not successful for an unknown reason
>       [ERR] 
>       The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (6.0.1.67).
>       Running "sencha package upgrade" may resolve the error described above.

I am able to create the app in separate folder using above method,
but in above case, what is wrong ?

Comment: Check if you are creating the app in the empty folder and if in the path to that folder there aren't any other apps / workspace created with older Cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, if the user do not have write permission it' getting above error.

I changed folder permission
by using

```
sudo chmod 777 /see
```

This resolved my issue.